# How to use collection in tensorflow to preserve my own object

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use tf.add_to_collection() to preserve my own object in order to get them easily later.
Here is the code segment:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, scope, is_training=True):
```

add object to collection:

```
for i in xrange(num_gpus):
    with tf.device("/gpu:%d"%i):
        with tf.name_scope("tower_%d"%i) as scope:
            m = Model.Model(scope)
            tf.add_to_collection("train_model", m)
```

get object from the collection:

```
models = tf.get_collection("train_model")
```

the code works fine, but i get a warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing train_model.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'Model' object has no attribute 'name
```

what shoud i do to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is (probably) produced when you call [`tf.train.Saver.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.save), and it attempts to write out a "MetaGraph" that represents the contents of the `tf.Graph`, including the contents of all of the graph's collections.

The simplest way to avoid the warning is to pass `write_meta_graph=False` when calling `saver.save()`. However, this leaves you without a MetaGraph to import later.

If you want to save the MetaGraph *and*  avoid the warning, you need to implement the necessary hooks (`to_proto` and `from_proto`) for serializing your `Model` object as a protocol buffer in the [`tf.train.MetaGraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d3822f06ca4440bf33d9034022e81ba4620f99c1/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.proto#L31) serialization format. The [MetaGraph tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/meta_graph/) explains how to do this, but the basic idea is as follows:

1. Define a protocol buffer (`ModelProto`) that describes the content of the `Model` object.
2. Define a `model_to_proto()` function that serializes a `Model` into a `ModelProto`:

   ```
   def model_to_proto(model):
       ret = ModelProto()
       # Set fields of `ret` from `model`.
       return ret
   ```
3. Define a `model_from_proto()` function that deserializes a `ModelProto` and returns a `Model`:

   ```
   def model_from_proto(model_proto):
       # Construct a `Model` from the fields of `model_proto`.
       return Model(...)
   ```
4. Register your functions for the `"train_model"` collection. This currently uses an undocumented function, called [`register_proto_function()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d3822f06ca4440bf33d9034022e81ba4620f99c1/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L4274):

   ```
   from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

   ops.register_proto_function("train_model",
                               proto_type=ModelProto,
                               to_proto=model_to_proto,
                               from_proto=model_from_proto)
   ```